# Add Content to Backend Editing Forms

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, admin-panel, fieldsets

I've build a module that creates a new manageable entity to Magento, including the Backend Forms.

What I now want to do is to display custom content above the form editing segment and below the title.

[image: Below the Title and above the Edit Segment I want to inject my own HTML content for the user]

From what I understand I'd start by creating a new Fieldset and create a new element that is not text, textarea, image upload or whatsoever but own content. This might take place in `/Edit/Tab/Form.php`?

What code is needed to create a new fieldset with (dynamic) content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was to make usage of `note` in the `Form.php`.

This code helped me:

```
$fieldset->addField('note', 'note', array(
    'text' => Mage::helper('contactform')->__('My content: %s', 'more content...'),
));
```